# SSL Error when sending email via amazon-ses-mailer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ses

I found this post [Using Amazon SES with Rails ActionMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798437/using-amazon-ses-with-rails-actionmailer) and followed the examples found on https://github.com/abronte/Amazon-SES-Mailer but I'm getting this error when sending the mail

```
    "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed"
```

config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = AmazonSes::Mailer.new(
    :secret_key => 'AKIAJ*******',
    :access_key => 'Ahs08*********'
)
```

sending message:

```
mailer = ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = AmazonSes::Mailer.new(
    :secret_key => 'AKI*******',
    :access_key => 'Ah***********'
  )
mailer.deliver( UserMailer.test(@this_user.email).encoded )
```

Why am I having SSL Errors here? I tried another configuration using smtp with personal gmail account and its sending the email just fine. Is it a problem with SES? How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you on HTTPS when sending it? Same error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the SES Mailer gem anymore. SES used to support TLS wrappers only but as of March 7th 2012...

[Amazon SES now supports STARTTLS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1387)

As stated in an answer at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9954404/353286). It should be as simple as...

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  :user_name => "..." # Your SMTP user here.
  :password => "...", # Your SMTP password here.
  :authentication => :login,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```