# `method_missing': undefined method `add_delivery_method' for ActionMailer::Base:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Hi I am trying to initialize the ActionMailer::Base:Class with some data:

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :ses, AWS::SES::Base,
  :access_key_id     => '0PxxxxxxxxxxxxS8Dyyy',
  :secret_access_key => 'aJxxxxxxxxxxxxx2Tpppa+ZQ6dddddddkN2'
```

But this throws an error:

```
`method_missing': undefined method `add_delivery_method' for ActionMailer::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

My Rails version - `3.2.13`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, what you are trying to do should be in an environment file, i.e. `config/environments/production.rb`. Do it like this:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    :user_name => "..." # Your SMTP user here.
    :password => "...", # Your SMTP password here.
    :authentication => :login,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Did you take a look at this question: [Using Amazon SES with Rails ActionMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798437/using-amazon-ses-with-rails-actionmailer)?